# Prove that $f$ is a continuous function at $x_0$ if and only if $\mu(\{x_0\})=0$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on the $\sigma$-algebra of the Borel set in $\mathbb R$.
For every $x\in \mathbb R$, $f(x)=\mu(-\infty ,x)$.
Please help me prove that $f$ is a continuous function at the point $x_0$ if and only if $\mu(\{x_0\})=0$.

For the first way, which is that if $f$ is a continuous function at the point $x_0$ then $\mu(\{x_0\})=0$, I tried the follow:

$f$ is a continuous function at the point $x_0$ then for every $\varepsilon>0$ exsist $\delta>0$ so that for every $x\in \mathbb R$ that $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f(x_0)-f(x)|<\varepsilon $.

$x_0 \in [x_0,x_0+\delta/3]$

$|f(x_0+\delta/3)-f(x_0 )|= 
\mu(-\infty,x_0+\delta/3)-μ(-\infty,x_0 )= 
\mu(-\infty,x_0)+\mu({x_0 })+\mu(x_0,x_0+δ/3)-\mu(-∞,x_0 )<\varepsilon$

Therefor $\mu({x_0 })+\mu(x_0,x_0+\delta/3)<\varepsilon$.

Since $\mu(x)≥0$ for every $x\in \mathbb R$, $\mu({x_0})=0$.

Please help me prove the other way (if $\mu(\{x_0\})=0$ then $f$ is a continuous function at the point $x_0$).

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The continuity of the measure $\mu$ implies

$$f(x_n) \to \mu(-\infty,x) \qquad \text{as} \, n \to \infty$$

for any sequence $x_n \uparrow x$. Similarly, since $\mu$ is a finite measure, one can show

$$f(x_n) \to \mu(-\infty,x] \qquad \text{as} \, n \to \infty$$

for any sequence $x_n \downarrow x$. Conclude that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $\mu(\{x\})=0$.